# How do I delay imageviews from changing

Tags: android

Hello I'm trying to delay imageviews to give a perception that they are being taken out one by one. I've tried

[Thread.Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds?lq=1)

[CountDownTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433336/want-to-display-number-with-1sec-delay?rq=1)

[Runnable/Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199191/how-to-set-delay-in-android-onclick-function)

But they either only delay once and both imageviews change at the same time or do not delay at all. For some reference I'm trying to do something like

```
 private void delaycard(final int Card) {

        newcard(Card); //Delay this before it is called
    }
```

Willing to try/retry anything at this point

Comment: I'm confused as to why handler wouldn't work. What're you trying to do with it?

Comment: The handler works but only delays the first imageview. Both imageviews show after the the handler is run. without a delay inbtween them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, try something like this:

```
                    Handler h = new Handler();
                    //for the number of images we have
                    for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {

                        //we create a runnable for that action
                        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                newCard(card);
                            }
                        };

                        //this is the amount of time to delay it by
                        delay = delay + 500;
                        //effectively, we're creating a series of runnables at the same time
                        //but they activate one after the other in .5s intervals
                        h.postDelayed(r, delay);
                    }
```

Comment: This worked except that I didn't need a for loop, what was happening is that I wasn't making more than 1 runnable. Can you explain some of this code as I want to learn how to do it in the future.

Comment: A handler is a sort of listener on your main thread that you can insert commands (runnables) into, which you do via `h.postDelayed(r, delay)`. By incrementing `delay` value, what you're saying is basically, "I have x runnables, now run them at these points in time" (.5, 1, 1.5, etc). It's a bit of an illusion in that you actually give out all your orders at the same time; they just appear to run at different times because of the delay.

Answer (score 0):

put this inside your method

```
     Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
       public void run() {
           newCard(Card);
       }
     }, 100);
```

Comment: When I run the code delaycard(21); delaycard(22); both imageviews (from newCard(Card) show at the same time. The first one is delayed but the second one isn't.

Comment: Owww so it's many, then what you need is thread pool use nostra13/universalimageloader for displaying images instead, it's very useful and it also has many other features. Happy coding. 
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader